# ADT doesn't show up in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I passed all the steps written at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html regarding "Downlaod the ADT Plugin" but when Eclipes restarts I don't get the "Welcome to Android Development" message. I don't get any "new android app" either under NEW menu. I tried also to check menu visibility through "customize perspective" but can't find any Android menu. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Erez

Answer (score 2):

```
Hello!
Are you configure your Android SDK location?
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see Window->Preferences->Android  - does it mean that the plug-in instalation went wrong somehow?

Comment: I think yes. Are you install plugin using menu "Help -> Install new software"?

Comment: Yes I did. I succeed to overcome the problem in two manners: 1) I uninstalled ADT, took an exisiting Android project and opened it on my Eclipse and then installed ADT again. 2) I installed it on my Linux computer and everything worked smoothly. Anyhow, thanks a lot for your help!